# Where should I put this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, non-mainstream-physics

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: *[Is it sufficient to have some anti-gravity generator to make an Alcubierre drive?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672741/)*

Where should I ask this question?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is:

> But if we managed to generate anti-gravity with some machine and manipulate it ...

This is firmly in non-mainstream territory since there is no such thing as *anti-gravity* in mainstream physics, and as such any questions about on this site are going to be closed.

In principle *exotic matter* could exist, and this can create systems that have a gravitational repulsion, but exotic matter has never been observed and there are some excellent theoretical reasons for believing it cannot exist i.e. it would violate conservation of energy.

Incidentally in your question you have the common confusion between *exotic matter* and *antimatter*. As far as gravity is concerned there is no difference between matter and antimatter, and in particular antimatter does not have a negative mass.

You can discuss this in the Physics SE chat room, but you need to have a reputation of at least 20 to use the chat rooms. If you can get this level of rep I'd be happy to discuss it there. However you won't be able to ask your question, or any similar questions, on the main site.

Comment: Give that chat room

Comment: @ErdelvonMises [This is the main Physics Stack Exchange chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).